# Remove blank space around plot's empty labels

Tags: pgfplots, standalone

I have the following MWE

```
%!TEX program=lualatex
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.16,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xtick=\empty,
    xticklabels=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    yticklabels=\empty,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style = {
        group size = 2 by 1,
        x descriptions at = edge bottom,
        y descriptions at = edge left,
    },
    xtick=\empty,
    xticklabels=\empty,
]
\nextgroupplot[
    axis y line* = left,
]

\nextgroupplot[
    axis y line* = right,
]
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There should be no ticks and no labels (first figure). However, it leaves a blank margin where x and y labels would be.
I want to trim this margin, like it happens with the top and right ones.
How can I do it?

[image: Result]

My actual goal is to get something like the second figure.
I keep the labels only on the left plot with `y descriptions at = edge left`, and I remove the middle axes to highlight the continuity of data.
Here I have the blank margin on the right side (and, in this example, also on the bottom, but there will be labels there).

Comment: `border={... .... ... ... }` option of `standalone` can be used to trim.

Comment: Do you have an example? I just tried, and I can increase the margin (using `margin` as well), but not reduce it. Also, the margin is already zero on top and right sides without any options.

Answer (score 2):

Use negative lengths in `border={<left> <bottom> <right> <top>}` to trim. I call this approach as "barbarian method".

```
\documentclass[border={-6.5pt -6.5ptpt 0pt 0pt},tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.16,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xtick=\empty,
    xticklabels=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    yticklabels=\empty,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style = {
        group size = 2 by 1,
        x descriptions at = edge bottom,
        y descriptions at = edge left,
    },
    xtick=\empty,
    xticklabels=\empty,
]
\nextgroupplot[
    axis y line* = left,
]

\nextgroupplot[
    axis y line* = right,
]
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your method works (sort of) only for the first plot but not for the second one. If you adjust the dimensions such that it works for the second, it won't work for the first.

Comment: @marmot: The second one is intentionally left as your exercise. :-)

Comment: Cool, I did not know `margin/border` could be negative. I would prefer a solution that does not need manual tuning, but it is good to know this brute force method.

Comment: @marmot, ArtificialStupidity: You can change the border inside the `standalone` document for all future pages using `\standaloneconfig{border=...}`. See the manual of `standalone` for more details, especially page 9.

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want this, you could just take the empty nodes out of the bounding box. The quickest way to do this is brutal:

```
\tikzset{every node/.append style={overlay}}
```

To have specific nodes contributing to the bounding box, you can say e.g.

```
yticklabel style={overlay=false},
```

Together with `trim`s one thus gets

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.16,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,every node/.append style={overlay}]
\begin{axis}[
    xtick=\empty,
    xticklabels=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    yticklabels=\empty,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={overlay},trim axis group right]
\begin{groupplot}[yticklabel style={overlay=false},
    group style = {
        group size = 2 by 1,
        x descriptions at = edge bottom,
        y descriptions at = edge left,
    },
    xtick=\empty,
    xticklabels=\empty,
]
\nextgroupplot[
    axis y line* = left,
]

\nextgroupplot[
    axis y line* = right,
]
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Having seen the [suggestion to trim the bounding box by dimensions that have been determined by hand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464376/121799), I am thinking to call my proposal "brutal but at least somewhat elegant". ;-)

Comment: I need the labels on the left plot, but I managed to adapt your suggestion. I added the `\tikzset{}` command right at the end of *each of the right plots* (in my plot I actually have several rows).

Comment: @Claudio Actually the labels are in (in the current version of my answer), but it is nice that you have found your own solution!

Comment: But now there is again the blank space on the right, which is what I want to get rid of (on the bottom I actually have labels). I tried adding `yticklabel style={overlay}` to the right-side `\nextgroupplot[]`, but that did not work.

Comment: @Claudio You're right. I looked at the manual, where there is quite a discussion on trimming the plots, which I used in my update.

Comment: `trim axis group right` does the job almost perfectly (while `append style={overlay}` messes up outer legends). However, it also trims half of the right axis line. On screen it is not too noticeable unless zooming in, but I need to try it on printed paper as well.

Comment: @Claudio Of course the overlay messes outer legends. But there were no legends in your code, and in my answer it is written how to remove the overlay from selected nodes.